# A problem occurred configuring root project 'cordapp-template-java-release-V4'

Tags: java, corda

Was trying to run a cordapp example from  https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java.git .
then I met with an error.
[image]

```
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'cordapp-template-java-release-V4'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:5.0.12.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/5.0.12/cordapp-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/5.0.12/cordapp-5.0.12.pom'.
               > repo.maven.apache.org
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/5.0.12/cordapp-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/5.0.12/cordapp-5.0.12.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordapp:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/5.0.12/cordapp-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/5.0.12/cordapp-5.0.12.pom'.
               > software.r3.com
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:5.0.12.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/cordformation/5.0.12/cordformation-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/cordformation/5.0.12/cordformation-5.0.12.pom'.
               > repo.maven.apache.org
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/cordformation/5.0.12/cordformation-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/cordformation/5.0.12/cordformation-5.0.12.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:cordformation:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordformation/5.0.12/cordformation-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordformation/5.0.12/cordformation-5.0.12.pom'.
               > software.r3.com
   > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:5.0.12.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/quasar-utils/5.0.12/quasar-utils-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/corda/plugins/quasar-utils/5.0.12/quasar-utils-5.0.12.pom'.
               > repo.maven.apache.org
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/quasar-utils/5.0.12/quasar-utils-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/net/corda/plugins/quasar-utils/5.0.12/quasar-utils-5.0.12.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
      > Could not resolve net.corda.plugins:quasar-utils:5.0.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/quasar-utils/5.0.12/quasar-utils-5.0.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/quasar-utils/5.0.12/quasar-utils-5.0.12.pom'.
               > software.r3.com
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom'.
               > repo.maven.apache.org
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom'.
               > jcenter.bintray.com
      > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE.
         > Could not get resource 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.2.RELEASE.pom'.
               > software.r3.com
```

Comment: Plain text rather than an image would be more useful.

Comment: The file exists: https://software.r3.com/artifactory/corda-releases/net/corda/plugins/cordapp/5.0.12/ Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: @opticyclic I have updated the full error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @opticlyptic for pointing this out in the comments above. It's worth mentioning that sometimes the repositories do have blips or outages.

If this is still an issue double check your gradle repositories. The latest version of this should be software.r3.com.
You can find an example of gradle repositories with that here: https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java/blob/release-V4/repositories.gradle

Comment: I have changed the gradle repo as per your shared link, but the same issue exists.